# WiX – copy arbitrary files

Tags: c#, wix

The folder where my setup.exe is located contains a subfolder `CAL`having files named something like `xyz1234.cal` – their names vary from customer to customer. These files have to be copied into a folder `CAL` in the target directory.
So I created a CustomAction and a C# dll which uses the `File.Copy()` function. My C# function receives the strings `srcDir` and `destDir` as parameters, e.g. `D:\installation\CAL` and `C:\MyApp\CAL`.
However, when I check the existence of the folders with `Directory.Exists(srcDir)`, an Exception is thrown, although the directory `D:\installation\CAL` exists:

`ERROR in custom action myFunction System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\Installer\MSID839.tmp-\D:\installation\CAL'.`

This happens no matter whether the CustomAcion is executed immediate or deferred. `C:\Windows\Installer\MSID839.tmp-\` seems to be the path of the executed assembly, but I certainly don’t want to have it as a part of the FullPath. How can I get rid of it?

CustomAction and properties are defined like so:
`<CustomAction Id='myCA' BinaryKey='myCABin' DllEntry='myFunction' Execute="deferred" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no"/>
    <Property Id="myCA" Value="Arg1=[CURRENTDIRECTORY];Arg2=[INSTALLDIR]" />`

The parameters are used like so:

```
CustomActionData data = session.CustomActionData;
string srcDir = data["Arg1"]+ "\\CAL";
string destDir = data["Arg2"]+ "\\CAL";
if (Directory.Exists(srcDir))
    // copy files
```

Comment: Let's show fragment where you set properties of your custom action (also an extract from your custom action may help). It may be wrong properties you're setting for your custom action or (improbable) the way you use them for File.Copy()

Comment: That's strange. Write `srcDir` to log file, right after it is initialized, just to be sure.

Comment: @Dialecticus: When I log `srcDir`, I get `D:\installation\CAL`. When I log `Path.GetFullPath(srcDir)' I get `C:\Windows\Installer\MSID839.tmp-\D:\installation\CAL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your app and it works fine. Here is my wix code (it's inside my product node):

```
<CustomAction Id='Test' BinaryKey='RegistryHelperCA' DllEntry='Test' Execute="deferred" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no"/>
<Property Id="Test" Value="Arg1=[CURRENTDIRECTORY];Arg2=[INSTALLDIR]" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="Test" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My custom action:

```
    [CustomAction("Test")]
    public static ActionResult Test(Session session)
    {
        string dir = session.CustomActionData["Arg1"];
        session.Log("DIRECTORY equals " + dir);

        if (Directory.Exists(dir))
            session.Log("Success");

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

It spits out dir as `C:\Users\user\Desktop`. Verify you aren't assigning to your `CURRENTDIRECTORY` property anywhere and, if you don't find anything, try setting your custom action to `Execute="immediate"` and accessing the data like this

`string srcDir = session["CURRENTDIRECTORY"]+ "\\CAL";`

If that doesn't work, surely that property is being overwritten somewhere. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on the right track that the property is being overwritten, because if I pass hard coded strings as parameter everything works nicely. Now the question is: how can I transform or wrap the property's original content so that only the desired path is passed?

Comment: @Germany'snextDilbert I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems to me that what you should be doing is searching for all instances of `CURRENTDIRECTORY`, finding where it's being overwritten, and fixing the code. If that's not what you're asking, could you elaborate?

Comment: Your tip making execution immediate helped - thanks.

Comment: @Germany'snextDilbert You're welcome! If that resolved your problem, would you mind marking the answer as accepted? If it didn't, please don't.

Comment: your answer was 50% as I found GetTargetPath() by myself. But as it was the initial spark I'll give you the credit :-)

Answer (score 0):

After some trial-and-error-sessions I found that `Directory.Exists(srcDir)` and `Directory.Exists(destDir)` didn't work, because the not the values but the property names are passed as parameter to the `Exist()` function - in contrast to `session.Log(srcDir)` which properly yields the value.

Finally I ended up with setting `execute="immediate"` and retrieving the values like so:

```
srcDir = session["CURRENTDIRECTORY"];
destDir = session.GetTargetPath("INSTALLDIR");
```